# Flex appending history tracking elements below application

Tags: css, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, history

I've got a Flex application that uses link buttons. As soon as I incorporated the link buttons (I assume) the Flex framework started putting history tracking elements below the app in the DOM. For example IE6-8 get an iframe element with id of `ie_historyFrame`, chrome/safari get a `safari_rememberDiv` and FF gets a `firefox_anchorDiv`.

Now, there would be no problem if these elements were hidden by the framework, but they're not. The sit underneath the Flex app (visually and in the DOM) and have a bunch of serialized history data.

I was wondering, is there a way to hide them through configuration or code? I know I could hide them via CSS but it just seems nasty that I'd have to use CSS for something that Flex is supposed to manage. I want the application to be site independent.

Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that flex creates a history folder with a history.js and history.css file. History.js controls the history data and history.css - you guessed it - hides the history elements. So the solution is to just use the history.css file on pages with the flex app.

Why the developers did not make this configurable, i don't know....

Comment: If you disable the integration with browser navigation it should regenerate the html-template directory and remove the history related files.

Comment: I did try doing what you suggested, but the history stuff remained, not sure why though

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using Flex Builder, go into the project's properties under the "Flex Compiler" options and uncheck the "Enable integration with browser navigation" checkbox.

Comment: thanks, sounds promising. will give it a shot when i get in to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put `historyManagementEnabled="false"` on `<mx:Application>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by brd6644 worked for me. You have to recreate the files then export the application.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using SWFAddress or something else of that nature? Flex doesn't have this functionality and LinkButtons don't make any ExternalInterface calls.

Comment: nope, im a newbie at flex so i didnt use anything complicated - just the elements that can be found in the drag and drop interface. i just noticed it started behaving like this after i added the link buttons...